# I tried to install Golang in Kali Linux and it's showing the following error

Tags: linux, kali-linux, golang

[image]
Once go-lang is installed, if I type `go version` and press enter in the same terminal which I used to install go-lang, it works and it shows me the go version. If I open a new terminal and enter the same command `go version`, it shows "command not found".

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screenshot, it's clear that you modify your `PATH` variable in the terminal where `go version` succeeded, but not in the terminal where it failed.

Consider adding the modification to your shell's initialization files.  If you are using the `zsh` shell (default on Kali Linux), modify the path in `~/.zshrc`, possibly at the end of the file.

```bsh
path+=( /usr/local/go/bin )
```

The change would be active in any interactive `zsh` shell started from that point on-wards (i.e. not in existing shell sessions).  You may obviously run that line in any existing terminal to have them find the `go` application, without the need to restart the terminal.